# How to get Page border style using Microsoft.Office.Interop?

Tags: vb.net

I have to verify the style of page border of Microsoft Word. I have to validate whether border style is of type `box page border`. I'm using Microsoft `interop dll` in my project.

I have used following code, but it returns true for other border styles too.

```
m_doc.Sections.Item(1).Borders.OutsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following Code

```
If (m_doc.Sections(1).Borders(WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft).LineStyle >= 1 And
m_doc.Sections(1).Borders(WdBorderType.wdBorderRight).LineStyle >= 1 And
m_doc.Sections(1).Borders(WdBorderType.wdBorderRight).LineStyle >= 1 And
m_doc.Sections(1).Borders(WdBorderType.wdBorderTop).LineStyle = 1) Then
    'Your Code
End If
```

**1=Line Style Single Border**